# Flash media server with php

Tags: php, flash, flash-media-server, amfphp, flash-cs5

We want to build an application that allows the user to record a video using their webcam on our site using flash and save the URL in a database using PHP. So that we can allow the user to send the video's to other users etc.

Also we want to offer the user the possibility to upload their movies (per mail and with PHP) and convert them to flash movies, can this also be done using Flash media server? (maybe in combination with AMFPHP)

Thanks so much

Greetings,

Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the video conversion part, I strongly recommend ffmpeg.  There is a PHP extension for it, or you can just call it with exec (probably easier).

Comment: The conversion part is now indeed covered by ffmpeg. It's too bad that flash media server doesn't handle this by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using FMS.  I would suggest that you look into Red5 as well.